# PDF.JS ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am currently trying to implement PDF.JS into my ASP.Net MVC 4 web application. I bundled the appropriate scripts and I am using the scripts below to render the PDF. I ran into this JavaScript Error with Font Face. "Failed to construct 'FontFace': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present." Any help would be appreciated.

```
PDFJS.disableFontFace = true;
PDFJS.getDocument('/Content/helloworld.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    // Using promise to fetch the page
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        //
        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        //
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        //
        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        //
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
});
```